# unable to setup django in production on EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, django

I have set up an EC2 instance with Ubuntu and able to login via ssh.

Now I have installed Apache, MySQL (worked fine). I need to install Django and configure it to run smoothly with apache. I have tried doing so but unable to configure it. can you please provide me instructions for how to setup all this step by step after login into EC2 via SSH.